# Is it possible to deploy a maven multimodule project as a single artifact on Nexus?

Tags: maven, module, pom.xml, maven-plugin, nexus

I have a maven multi-module project similar to this:

```
- myService-parent
| - myService
| - myService-openApiDocs
| - miService-eventsDefinition
```

That I would like to deploy on Nexus as a single artifact, like this:

```
Maven-repo
|- myService
|        | -  <version>
|                | - maven-metadata.xml
|                | - <my service artifact>
|                            | - myService.pom
|                            | - myService.jar
|                            | - myService-openApiDocs.zip
|                            | - myService-eventsDefinition.json
```

With the `maven-metadata.xml` similar to this:

```
<metadata modelVersion="1.1.0">

    <groupId>com.myCompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>myService</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>

    <versioning>
        <snapshot>
            <timestamp>...</timestamp>
            <buildNumber>...</buildNumber>
        </snapshot>
        <lastUpdated>...</lastUpdated>
        <snapshotVersions>
            <snapshotVersion>
                <classifier>open-api-docs</classifier>
                <extension>zip</extension>
                <value>...</value>
                <updated>...<updated>
            </snapshotVersion>
            <snapshotVersion>
                <extension>jar</extension>
                <value>...</value>
                <updated>...</updated>
            </snapshotVersion>
            <snapshotVersion>
                <extension>pom</extension>
                <value>...</value>
                <updated>...</updated>
            </snapshotVersion>
            <snapshotVersion>
                <classifier>event-definitions</classifier>
                <extension>json</extension>
                <value>...</value>
                <updated>...</updated>
            </snapshotVersion>
        </snapshotVersions>
    </versioning>
</metadata>
```

But actually what I obtain on Nexus is the creation of one different artifact for each module, like this:

```
Maven-repo
|- myService-parent
|        | -  <version>
|                | - maven-metadata.xml
|                | - <my service-parent artifact>
|                             | - myService-parent.pom
|- myService
|        | -  <version>
|               | - maven-metadata.xml
|               | - <my service artifact>
|                            | - myService.pom
|                            | - myService.jar
|- myService-openApiDocs
|        | -  <version>
|               | - maven-metadata.xml
|               | - <my service-openApiDocs artifact>
|                            | - myService-openApiDocs.pom
|                            | - myService-openApiDocs.zip
|- myService-eventsDefinition
|        | -  <version>
|               | - maven-metadata.xml
|               | - <my service-eventsDefinition artifact>
|                            | - myService-eventsDefinition.pom
|                            | - myService-eventsDefinition.json
```

How can I define in maven the structure that the multi-module project has on nexus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no sensible way of doing this.

If you want one artifact in Nexus, then refactor the project to a single-module project that generates two attached side artifacts.